# Can this simple socket room code be shortened?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm going to make a multyplayer minigame with socket.io, node and react as front end. I got the room logic working, but I'm not that sure if that's the best way to do it especially on the side where player joins room. Here's my code, any tips that could help me improve this is really appreciated, ty!

///We will start from client where we create room

```
add() {
        socket.emit('create')
        this.setState({mode: 'player'}) //ignore this, part of react 
    }
```

///Now on the server we get this

```
socket.on('create', () => {
        socket.join(socket.id);
        io.in(socket.id).emit('join', 'U are in the room!')
        rooms.push(socket.id)   //ignore this
        socket.broadcast.emit('created', socket.id) ///ignore this
    })
```

//And finally on back to client, a simple check

```
socket.on('join', data => alert(data))
```

So we basically we created and joined the room, now comes the part when another player tries to join the room.

///On client we join the room (when clicking a button with e.target.value = room name)

```
join(e) {
        socket.emit('joined', e.target.value) //e.target.value == a room name
    }
```

//Now back to server

```
socket.on('joined', data => {
        socket.join(data) //we got the player in the room!
        io.in(data).emit('joined', 'Hello man, Im new here!') //do I really need this part?
    })
```

//And finally on client

```
socket.on('joined', (data) => {alert(data)}) //do I need this as well?
```

This is my room logic, the part I'm not sure about is the second one when player tries to join the room, I'm afraid it might be unnecessary code there, bacause I need to connect the socket only to the room on server, and the events will be emited from the creator socket.on...

Comment: What's the point of `socket.join(socket.id);`?  socket.io already puts a socket into a room that has the name of its ID.  So, there's need for you to do that at all.  It's already done for you.

Comment: Do you mean that socket.join() = socket.join(creator.socket.id)? In this case that's a little shortened on server side. What about the 'joined' event, can I shorten that?

Comment: No. I mean that you don't have to do any `.join(socket.id)` because socket.io already puts the socket in a room using the name of its id. You can shorten the join event to `socket.emit('join', 'U are in the room!')`.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me!

Comment: Since your code is working, you'll probably get a better response on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You could try asking there if you want more thorough feedback.